# centered nav with flexible left and right widths - percentage padding does not work

Tags: html, css, navigation, padding

**UPDATE:** Simplified HTML & CSS as per one of the answers below.  The problem is still occurring however.

I have a working nav that is something like this:

```
                item11item2item3    Centered    item4item5item6
```

I want to add padding between the items so it looks like this:

```
       item1     item2     item3    Centered    item4     item5     item6
```

The items on the *left* are *right-justified*.  The items on the *right* are *left-justified*.

**The Problem**

- If I use `float: right;` to justify the list, I get `item3   item2   item1`.
- If I use `float: left;` and set the container width to `auto`, I can get the correct layout, but only when I use `px` padding.
- When I use `%` padding like `padding-left: 3%;` it breaks and looks like this:

  ```
            item1     item2       Centered    item4     item5     item6
            item3
  ```

Here's my **HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
    <nav>
        <ul class="left">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="center">
            <li>Centered</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="right">
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
        </ul>   
    </nav>
</div>
```

Here's my **CSS**:

```
/* Reset */

html, body, nav, li {
  margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
}

/* Styles */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

nav {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav > ul.left {
    position: absolute;
    right: 55%;
}

nav > ul.left > li {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5%;
}

.center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    width: 10%;
}

.center li {
    text-align: center;
}

nav > ul.right {
    position: absolute;
    left: 55%;
    width: 45%;
}

nav > ul.right > li {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5%;
}
```

**Notes:**

- I'm using absolute positioning & containers in order to keep "Centered" perfectly centered even if the widths of the left and right nav items aren't identical.
- I'm using % based widths because it's a flexible layout (reponsive)
- the above code works ok, but I'd really like to make the padding percentage based so it's flexible.

So it *appears* that the `li-container` div inherits the width correctly and accounts for the padding when I use pixels, but not when I use percentages.  Is this typical behavior?  What is the solution?

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timshutes/4snNw/5/) in case you want to play around with it.

**ADDITIONAL UPDATE:**

The chief problem seems to be the need to have the "left" items right-justified.  If I use `float:right` then I get reverse order, which isn't good.  If I use `float:left` on the left items, then the order is correct, but I need to remove explicit width from the container, or the items aren't right-justified.  Removing explicit container width causes the issue I'm experiencing.

Comment: `<div>` is **not** a valid child of `<ul>`. The only allowed content is: "*Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.*", see [4.5.6 The ul element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element).

Comment: would it solve the problem to update from a ul > li nav to a div > li nav?

Comment: updated code to `nav > li` - which I think is valid now, right?

Comment: The only valid parent elements for `li` elements are: `ul, li, menu`, see w3.org [li – list item "Permitted parent elements"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-context)

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:* Here's a new solution. Hope this looks like expected. ;)

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <ul class="left">
        <li>Item 1 longer longer</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="centered">
        <li>Centered</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right">
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 700px;
}

nav > ul {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}

nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background: green;
    color: white;
}

nav > ul.centered {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    width: 20%;
    background: orange;
}

nav > ul.centered > li {
    display: block;
    background: orange;
}

nav > ul.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 40%;
}

nav > ul.left > li {
    float: right;
    padding: 2%;
}

nav > ul.right {
    position: absolute;
    left: 60%;
    max-width: 40%;
}

nav > ul.right > li {
    float: left;
    padding: 2%;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/PFJ4m/)

**Update**

The only way to get all things lined up, in the right order without any breaking ever is using `display: inline-block`. I've updated only the left side to demonstrate it.

**Final thoughts:** As this will never break, you have to set a `min-width` for the `<nav>`-element, otherwise the elements will overlap on screens that are too small. What you experienced before, when the width of the parent container of floating elements gets too small and they break into the next line, *is the expected behavior* for floating elements.

**Updated CSS**

```
nav > ul.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 40%;
    text-align: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}

nav > ul.left > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10%;
    line-height: auto;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try `display: inline-block`](http://jsfiddle.net/zqGgN/)

---

Here's also a link to my [first solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Nm2en/).

Comment: This solution won't work because it's dependent on each `li` being the same width, or at least the left and right `li` groups being the same width for the 'centered' `li` to actually be centered.  see: http://jsfiddle.net/timshutes/Nm2en/1/

Comment: with my CSS, although bulkier, the behavior is better, although I have the % width issue:  http://jsfiddle.net/timshutes/4snNw/4/

Comment: @timshutes OK, that wasn't clear in the quesion. Maybe I can think of something else.

Comment: @timshutes I've updated my answer. Hope I got it right this time. ;)

Comment: upvoted and updated my question.  Your solution ALMOST does it, however, the float right on the left `li` reverses my menu order.  I need the order to stay straight.  Any attempt at at float: left though and I get the padding issue.

Comment: @timshutes I've updated my answer. Hope, we finally made it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using the element inspector in Chrome on that fiddle, **with** the padding on 3% on `.left .li` I gather this:

`.left .li-container`'s calculated width: **128px**

Each individual `li`'s width: **43px**

You have three `li`'s --> 3 * 43 = **129px**

That would cause the width of the child li's to extend the parent container's width, thus wrapping to a new line. So it probably has to do with rounding off in the calculation of the actual width from that percentage value.

To compensate for this, I can only think of a jQuery/JS solution at the moment but I doubt you'd want that, and just want it in pure CSS.

**Note**: I would just add this as a comment but unfortunately I can't because that requires 50 rep. Sorry for not providing a complete answer!

Comment: That's interesting about rounding.  I wonder what the solution to that would be?

Comment: As I said, if jQuery is permitted, I have a very quick solution. Otherwise, I'll have to do some digging.

Comment: yeah I'd rather a CSS solution for this one.

Comment: +1 because I think your answer points to the correct solution, even if it's not a solution.  I updated my question to further clarify.

Comment: I think I've found a follow-up: CSS3's calc() function. That way you could do `padding-left: calc(3% - 1px);`

Comment: How about this? Seems ancient enough: http://webfx.eae.net/dhtml/cssexpr/cssexpr.html